# how to resolve 404 error using spring annonation?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC with annonation  and I am just trying a basic example for it. But I am receiving Http Stats 404 error. My files are as below : 
It is a maven project. request mapping is the part of controller which is used and jsp page only list.jsp to show that msg.
errors-HTTP Status 404 - /test1/view/list.jsp

```
public class ADConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        System.out.println("hjshjshdjkah");
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
    public ModelAndView list() {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Controller part methods@@@");
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("list", "message", message);  

    }
}
```

Comment: So, where is the list.jsp file located?

Comment: You want to avoid the status 404 error? or you want to handle the 404 error code? That means do you know that you will get 404 error already or you don't know why you are getting 404 error?